# Memory Allocation in MS Win32 Security Functions

Tags: c, security, winapi, memory

Why is it that the MS Security examples seem to use one memory allocation routine in the documentation for one function, and another one in a different one?

I have found an example where they actually use different ones at different points in the example code.  See the [`GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

This uses both `HeapAlloc` when allocating a SID and `LocalAlloc` when allocating a security descriptor.  Both allocations are freed before the example ends, why are they using different methods?  I've seen people use `::malloc` in blog examples.

Comment: I guess you could look at it as the example demonstrating that it doesn't matter how you allocate the memory you pass to those functions, since you own it and are responsible for freeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalAlloc` and `HeapAlloc` are the same in this case.  This was not always the case, but it has been for a decade at least.  I know, it's confusing, but it's all the result of legacy 16bit systems and backwards compatibility.  See this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa366596%28v=vs.85%29):

> Windows memory management does not provide a separate local heap and global heap, as 16-bit > Windows does. As a result, the global and local families of functions are equivalent and 
>   choosing between them is a matter of personal preference.

See also this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa366711%28v=vs.85%29):

> There is no difference between memory allocated from a private heap and that allocated by 
>   using the other memory allocation functions. For a complete list of functions, see the table 
>   in Memory Management Functions.

There are differences, so always read the documentation for the memory function.  For example, `CoTaskMemFree` handles NULL but `HeapFree` does not.  The different allocation functions will give you different degrees of control over how the memory is allocated and shared among OS objects (processes, etc).  But if you just want some plain old memory for your process, always check the documentation for the API you are using, as it may specify that you should use specific allocation or freeing functions, but otherwise, just pick one and be consistent.

As for why the documentation switches it up?  My guess is it was hacked on by more than one person over time, none of which were actual OS team members.  MSDN sample code is notoriously bad.  There should be a way for you to flag it or leave feedback on the MSDN page.

Comment: Yes it is, and 99% of the time it should really say the language is C, not C++, Yuck all those goto's.  Not a goto zealot, but there is no need in this case (I follow the rule, 'if and only if using a goto would make the code clearer, then use a goto, otherwise please don't')

Comment: I think I will follow your advise and flag it up by leaving feedback on the MSDN page.

Comment: There were many competing threads of thought on proper coding style that have historically run through Microsoft.  For certain domains of programming, specifically raw COM (with no ATL), the goto was frequently used as a cleanup mechanism.  There are legitimate arguments on both sides, but I think everyone will agree only the worst examples of this style made it into MSDN samples...

Answer (score 0):

MS Security examples do not use malloc as according to me the malloc function has the disadvantage of being run-time dependency,
HeapAlloc(which uses RtlReAllocateHeap) won't allocate memory for 0 sized pointers, where malloc would plus LocalAlloc have greater overhead than HeapAlloc, but less than malloc.